# SQL Server - current inventory with physical count

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-null

I feel as though I'm missing something extremely fundamental that should be obvious.  I'm basically trying to take the below data and calculate a fifth column:  Inventory_Current.

Example data:

| DateStamp | ProductID | Inventory_Change | Inventory_Count |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 | 100 | -300 | 100000 |
| 2021-07-01 | 200 | -700 | 50000 |
| 2021-07-02 | 100 | 200 | null |
| 2021-07-02 | 200 | -100 | null |
| 2021-07-03 | 100 | 500 | null |
| 2021-07-03 | 200 | 300 | null |
| 2021-07-04 | 100 | -1000 | 99500 |
| 2021-07-04 | 200 | -100 | null |
| 2021-07-05 | 100 | 100 | null |
| 2021-07-05 | 200 | 300 | 50500 |

Inventory_Count is generally only performed once a month, but sales dictate that Inventory_Change happens daily.  So I need to calculate current inventory levels based on the sum of the Inventory_Changes since the last Inventory_Count per ProductID.  The Example data is meant to succinctly capture this concept.

Expected result:

| DateStamp | ProductID | Inventory_Change | Inventory_Count | Inventory_Current |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2021-07-01 | 100 | -300 | 100000 | 99700 |
| 2021-07-01 | 200 | -700 | 50000 | 49300 |
| 2021-07-02 | 100 | 200 | null | 99900 |
| 2021-07-02 | 200 | -100 | null | 49200 |
| 2021-07-03 | 100 | 500 | null | 100400 |
| 2021-07-03 | 200 | 300 | null | 49500 |
| 2021-07-04 | 100 | -1000 | 99500 | 98500 |
| 2021-07-04 | 200 | -100 | null | 49400 |
| 2021-07-05 | 100 | 100 | null | 98600 |
| 2021-07-05 | 200 | 300 | 50500 | 50800 |

To calculate Inventory_Current, I'd roughly follow the below logic:

```
select
  DateStamp,
  ProductID,
  Inventory_Change,
  Inventory_Count,
  iif(Inventory_Count is not null,
    Inventory_Count+Inventory_Change,
    /*Do magic here*/
  ) as Inventory_Current
from
  Inventory
```

I've considered Itzik Ben-Gan's [Last non Null](https://www.itprotoday.com/sql-server/last-non-null-puzzle) concept (brilliant, btw), leveraging LAG, OVER PARTITION, or giving up (SQL dba is not my primary role, obviously).  It seems the big issue is all the solutions rely on a primary key, whereas my combination of DateStamp and ProductID seems to cause issues.

Even a link to some solid reading would be appreciated.  Or a good night's rest away from children.  :)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: So, for the sample data you have given, what are the expected results?

Comment: YOur expected results and sample data are the same

Comment: It said you were editing it after I tried to add the header, which I'd forgotten.  Got it now.  Sorry, I'm blaming my sick kid today.  My head is mush.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without expected results (at the time of writing), this is a guess, however, I am going to *guess* that you want to have a cumulative `SUM` of the value of `InventoryChange` and add that to the last non-`NULL` value of `InventoryCount`. If so then perhaps this is what you are after:

```sql
CREATE TABLE dbo.YourTable (DateStamp date,
                            ProductID int,
                            InventoryChange int,
                            InventoryCount int);
GO
INSERT INTO dbo.YourTable
VALUES('2021-07-01',100,-300 , 100000),
      ('2021-07-01',200,-700 , 50000),
      ('2021-07-02',100,200  ,null),
      ('2021-07-02',200,-100 , null),
      ('2021-07-03',100,500  ,null),
      ('2021-07-03',200,300  ,null),
      ('2021-07-04',100,-1000,  99500),
      ('2021-07-04',200,-100 , null),
      ('2021-07-05',100,100  ,null),
      ('2021-07-05',200,300  ,50500);
GO
WITH Groups AS(
    SELECT DateStamp,
           ProductID,
           InventoryChange,
           InventoryCount,
           COUNT(InventoryCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID ORDER BY DateStamp) AS Grp
    FROM dbo.YourTable)
SELECT DateStamp,
       ProductID,
       InventoryChange,
       CASE WHEN InventoryCount IS NOT NULL THEN InventoryCount + InventoryChange
            ELSE MAX(InventoryCount) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID,Grp) +
                 SUM(InventoryChange) OVER (PARTITION BY ProductID,Grp ORDER BY DateStamp)
       END AS InventoryCount
FROM Groups
ORDER BY DateStamp;

GO

DROP TABLE dbo.YourTable;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=949e8a6070e68512b1fbcef48b46089e)

If you don't want the value of `InventoryChange` to be counted on the row with the non-`NULL` value, you'll need a `CASE` expression inside the `SUM`.

Comment: Sorry it took me a bit to validate.  However, this worked perfectly, thank you.  For anyone looking, I did change the "END AS InventoryCount" to "END AS Inventory_Current" and put the InventoryCurrent back into the same select.  I still have to educate myself as to how this works, but the help is very appreciated.